# Duplicate GUID being created - Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an application where I am using Fluent NHibernate to talk to a SQLite database and saving objects. When I run the code below, all of the new items enter into the loop with an empty Guid (which is expected), but then once the SaveOrUpdate function runs, all of the new items all recieve the same Guid. I added session.flush() to see if I could flush the session and force a unique Guid...but no dice.

Any help would be appreciated!

**My Mapping File**

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb().Unique();
```

**The Code**

```
public void SaveItems()
    {
        using (ISession session = SessionProvider.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                foreach (Item item in this.Items)
                {
                    session.SaveOrUpdate(item);
                    session.Flush();
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure those the members of the Items collection are truly distinct objects, and not just multiple references to the same instance?

Comment: Man...you're totally right. That's what it was. Simple problem, but I would have never noticed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally this was a comment, but since it turned out to be correct it should be an answer instead:

Verify that the members of the Items collection are truly distinct objects, and not just multiple references to the same instance.